# $y^n=2x^n$ has no solution nonzero whole numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n \in N,  n\geq2$  .

Prove that equation $y^n=2x^n$ has no solution nonzero whole numbers.

I tried to prove it by induction but I got nothing. Any advices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Infinite descent works

Comment: Just generalize the irrationalilty proof of sqrt 2.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are odd, absurde and if  $y$ is even the power of the prime factor $2$ of $y$ is a multiple of $n$ and for $x$ you have  a multiple of $n$ plus $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hint : let $y^n = 2x^n$ have a solution in non-zero whole numbers for $n \geq 2$.

- Show that if $y , x$ is a solution, then $y$ must be even.
- Show therefore that $x$ is even.
- Show that $\frac y2 , \frac x2$ is a solution of the same equation.
- Show that starting from any given solution, we may thus obtain a solution with $y$ odd, a contradiction. Therefore, there can be no solution to start with.

Answer (score 0):

By taking out common factors we may assume that $x$ and $y$ are coprime. Then the equation implies that $2$ divides $x$ and not $y$, hence, by uniqueness of prime decomposition, $2^n$ should appear in the RHS: contradiction since $n>1$.